# Complicated(?) MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a database table loaded with about 1.3 million rows from web scraping. There aren't many fields, which might make this easier. Here are the columns: `url`, `keyword`, `data_ref`.

URL is repeated a bunch of times. Keyword may or may not be repeated, but appears no more than once per URL. data_ref may or may not appear more than once per URL. What I need to do is find the URL that appears the most times with any particular data_ref. It would be awesome to be able to get a count and then list the second-most-common after that.

How would a query like that be structured? I don't necessarily need a working example, just a push in the right direction.

The ideal output would be something like this:

```
Data Reference (by data_ref):
    123456
        https://www.somesite.com - 8 references
        https://www.someothersite.com - 8 references
    8765432
        https://www.athirdsite.com - 12 references
        http://www.yetanothersite.com - 6 references
Site Reference (by url):
    http://www.abcdefgh.net/p/index.htm - 92 references
```

Formatting this wouldn't be a problem once I figure out how to collect the right kind of data, but this is kind of the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Would you edit the question to include what would be the *ideal* output?

Comment: In addition to what @wallyk asked, can you also share what you have done to solve this.

Comment: Since you ask for pointers: Look at the group by and having clauses. Something like select count(url), url, data_ref from table group by url, data_ref should give you the number of times a url appears with a data_ref.  Having allows you to filter those results. Max() would allow you to find the max count to filter to find only the max.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, sounds like you might want to try the GROUP BY function.

Something like this perhaps:

SELECT COUNT(url), data_ref

FROM Table_name

GROUP BY url

ORDER BY COUNT(data_ref) DESC;

Comment: I so appreciate this! You've given me a great place to start. I can't give this a thumbs-up because my account is too new, but I hope someone does for me.